# Login using Putty for Hive

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-hdinsight

I created a `HDinsight Cluster` and was trying to log in to `Shell` using `Putty`
`<Clustername>-ssh.azurehdinsight.net` using the given credentials while creating the Cluster.

Having problems logging using `Putty` after I gave credentials it's showing access denied.

Are there any other permissions that I need to provide to log in using Putty?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of creating the cluster, you need to select the SSH option and specify the public key. This can then be used to submit jobs by logging in to the head node. I had blogged about it recently

https://nileshgule.blogspot.sg/2017/10/submit-apache-spark-job-from-command.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

No need any permissions that need to provided to log in using putty.

If you are using the following syntax to connect using putty(you will receive Access denied):

**ssh sshuser@clustername-ssh.azurehdinsight.net**

Use the following to connect using putty:

**sshuser@clustername-ssh.azurehdinsight.net**

You can securely connect to the below endpoints in the HDInsight cluster with an SSH client. you may refer [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-linux-use-ssh-unix).

You can also try the below method to connect HDInsight cluster using PuTTY.

Goto Configuration -> SSH + Cluster login -> copy the cluster name without ssh -> enter the details in PuTTy and click connect -> enter the password to connect.

Refer the below screenshots for more details.

[image]